# java.io.NotSerializableException in OutputPanel - Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish-3

I'm using `Glashfish 3` & `Primefaces 3.5`

**Small update**

---

I tried the following but without any luck.

1. Cleaned my application.
2. Re-Built the project.
3. Undeployed the app from Glassfish admin console.
4. Restarted Glassfish server.
5. Deployed again from JDeveloper.

---

While accessing my jsf page I'm getting the below exception in the browser.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel
```

And in my log:

```
WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:940)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)...
```

What may be wrong here.? It was working fine just the day before, and I've done no changes  (to the application or server) whatsoever.

**Update**

*Issue got resolved. There was an issue with my jsf file which somehow got corrupted. Thankfully I had a backup of it. 
Thanks all for you support and suggestion.*

Comment: Looks like a problem while trying to save or restore session data. You should restart the server and try again. If this doesn't help you should update the question with the complete exception stack trace and the relevant xhtml and java code.

Comment: Thanks for replying @unwichtich. I tried to clean, Build All, undeploy, deploy and restart the server. but nothing seems to be working. I'll update my question asap.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details about how you get the error: on page load? On page refresh? After pressing a button?

Comment: Sure @perissf. I'll post the relevent code and all shortly. Meanwhile, the error occurs after pressing the `Login` button which in turn should go to the home page. It is going to the `home` page but with this error.